# Mysql: Date Comparisons and a Join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query to pull available rooms and it joins a reservation table to see available rooms for a given period(start and end date).  I'm drawing a blank here and I think this is a pretty simple query, I just can't think of the best way to create it.

What I have so far that needs to be fixed

```
   SELECT *
     FROM room
LEFT JOIN reservation ON room.id = reservation.room_id
    WHERE reservation.id is null or 
          :startdate > reservation.enddate or 
          :enddate   < reservation.startdate
```

My above query will return results for rooms with multiple reservations that may satisfy the where clause even though there could be reservation within the date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using a `not exists` predicate which I find intuitive:

```
SELECT *
FROM room
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM reservation 
    WHERE room.id = room_id
    AND 
      :startdate < enddate 
    AND 
      startdate < :enddate)
```

The logic says *return all rooms for which there doesn't exists any related reservations between the given dates*.

Comment: I didn't think to use the "not exists" predicate but this query will still return a room that has multiple reservations and one satisfies the where clause even though a reservation might conflict with the given start and end dates.

Comment: @Ralph Oh right, seems I have the logic wrong... hang on

Comment: I do appreciate the effort but this will still return results that shouldn't be returned.  According to your query and mine, If there is a reservation within the date range and also another reservation in the future that satisfies the where clause, it will still list the room as being available now.

Comment: @Ralph Could you gives some example? The logic seem sound to me and when I test it all rooms that have reservations that overlap with the range are excluded. See this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a64b2/2

Comment: actually, your right, after testing I realized it works.  Thanks for your input.